# Molecule complaining about "[703] Should change default metadata: description" while running the basic test

Tags: python, docker, ansible, molecule

I couldn't run the  `molecule test` command as it throws below error, while I can run individual commands without any errors ( Also provided --debug o/p below)

```
[701] Role info should contain platforms
/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml:1
{'meta/main.yml': {'__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'dependencies': [], u'galaxy_info': {u'description': u'your description', u'license': u'license (GPLv2, CC-BY, etc)', u'author': u'your name', u'company': u'your company (optional)', u'galaxy_tags': [], '__line__': 2, '__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'min_ansible_version': 1.2}, '__line__': 1}}

[703] Should change default metadata: author
/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml:1
{'meta/main.yml': {'__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'dependencies': [], u'galaxy_info': {u'description': u'your description', u'license': u'license (GPLv2, CC-BY, etc)', u'author': u'your name', u'company': u'your company (optional)', u'galaxy_tags': [], '__line__': 2, '__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'min_ansible_version': 1.2}, '__line__': 1}}

[703] Should change default metadata: description
/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml:1
{'meta/main.yml': {'__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'dependencies': [], u'galaxy_info': {u'description': u'your description', u'license': u'license (GPLv2, CC-BY, etc)', u'author': u'your name', u'company': u'your company (optional)', u'galaxy_tags': [], '__line__': 2, '__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'min_ansible_version': 1.2}, '__line__': 1}}

[703] Should change default metadata: company
/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml:1...
```

however if I run below commands it works perfectly.
So, can anyone points out why whole test is failing, what should I do?

1. molecule create
2. molecule list

```
Validation completed successfully.
Instance Name    Driver Name    Provisioner Name    Scenario Name    Created    Converged
---------------  -------------  ------------------  ---------------  ---------  -----------
instance         docker         ansible             default          true       false
```

3. molecule converge

```
Validation completed successfully.
--> Test matrix

└── default
    ├── dependency
    ├── create
    ├── prepare
    └── converge

--> Scenario: 'default'
--> Action: 'dependency'
Skipping, missing the requirements file.
--> Scenario: 'default'
--> Action: 'create'
Skipping, instances already created.
--> Scenario: 'default'
--> Action: 'prepare'
Skipping, prepare playbook not configured.
--> Scenario: 'default'
--> Action: 'converge'

    PLAY [Converge] ****************************************************************

    TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
    ok: [instance]

    TASK [molecule-testing : Molecule Hello World!] ********************************
    ok: [instance] => {
        "msg": "Hello, World!"
    }

    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    instance                   : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

4. molecule list

```
 molecule list
--> Validating schema /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/molecule/default/molecule.yml.
Validation completed successfully.
Instance Name    Driver Name    Provisioner Name    Scenario Name    Created    Converged
---------------  -------------  ------------------  ---------------  ---------  -----------
instance         docker         ansible             default          true       true
```

5. molecule destroy
6. molecule list

```
--> Validating schema /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/molecule/default/molecule.yml.
Validation completed successfully.
Instance Name    Driver Name    Provisioner Name    Scenario Name    Created    Converged
---------------  -------------  ------------------  ---------------  ---------  -----------
instance         docker         ansible             default          true       false
```

folder structure looks like this

```
.
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── molecule
│   └── default
│       ├── Dockerfile.j2
│       ├── INSTALL.rst
│       ├── molecule.yml
│       ├── playbook.yml
│       └── tests
│           ├── test_default.py
│           └── test_default.pyc
├── README.md
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
└── vars
    └── main.yml
```

molecule.yml file is

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
lint:
  name: yamllint
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image: centos:7
    privileged: true
    command: /sbin/init
    volume_mounts:
        - "/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro"
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  lint:
    name: ansible-lint
scenario:
  name: default
```

tasks\main.yml -->

```
---
# tasks file for molecule-testing
- name: Molecule Hello World!
  debug:
    msg: Hello, World!
```

version of molecule and ansible are as follow

```
molecule --version
molecule, version 2.22

ansible --version
ansible 2.8.4
 config file = None
 configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
 ansible python module location = /root/molecule_ansible2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
 executable location = /root/molecule_ansible2.7/bin/ansible
 python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

docker images

```
docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker.io/centos    7                   67fa590cfc1c        4 weeks ago         202 MB
```

sample output of `molecule --debug test` is

```
DEBUG: COMMAND
/root/molecule_ansible2.7/bin/ansible-lint -v --exclude=/root/.cache/molecule/molecule-testing/default /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/molecule/default/playbook.yml

    Examining /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/molecule/default/playbook.yml of type playbook
    Examining /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/tasks/main.yml of type tasks
    Examining /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/handlers/main.yml of type handlers
    Examining /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml of type meta
    [701] Role info should contain platforms
    /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml:1
    {'meta/main.yml': {'__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'dependencies': [], u'galaxy_info': {u'description': u'your description', u'license': u'license (GPLv2, CC-BY, etc)', u'author': u'your name', u'company': u'your company (optional)', u'galaxy_tags': [], '__line__': 2, '__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'min_ansible_version': 1.2}, '__line__': 1}}

    [703] Should change default metadata: author
    /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml:1
    {'meta/main.yml': {'__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'dependencies': [], u'galaxy_info': {u'description': u'your description', u'license': u'license (GPLv2, CC-BY, etc)', u'author': u'your name', u'company': u'your company (optional)', u'galaxy_tags': [], '__line__': 2, '__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'min_ansible_version': 1.2}, '__line__': 1}}

    [703] Should change default metadata: description
    /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml:1
    {'meta/main.yml': {'__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'dependencies': [], u'galaxy_info': {u'description': u'your description', u'license': u'license (GPLv2, CC-BY, etc)', u'author': u'your name', u'company': u'your company (optional)', u'galaxy_tags': [], '__line__': 2, '__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'min_ansible_version': 1.2}, '__line__': 1}}

    [703] Should change default metadata: company
    /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml:1
    {'meta/main.yml': {'__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'dependencies': [], u'galaxy_info': {u'description': u'your description', u'license': u'license (GPLv2, CC-BY, etc)', u'author': u'your name', u'company': u'your company (optional)', u'galaxy_tags': [], '__line__': 2, '__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'min_ansible_version': 1.2}, '__line__': 1}}

    [703] Should change default metadata: license
    /root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml:1
    {'meta/main.yml': {'__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'dependencies': [], u'galaxy_info': {u'description': u'your description', u'license': u'license (GPLv2, CC-BY, etc)', u'author': u'your name', u'company': u'your company (optional)', u'galaxy_tags': [], '__line__': 2, '__file__': u'/root/.config/pip/molecule-testing/meta/main.yml', u'min_ansible_version': 1.2}, '__line__': 1}}

An error occurred during the test sequence action: 'lint'. Cleaning up.
```

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR;

These are errors/good practices reported by `ansible-lint` that you should fix. You can run the `lint` stage by its own by simply launching `molecule lint`.

From your current output, you only need to add some info in `meta/main.yml` in your role.

## What is happening exactly

Each `molecule` command (e.g. `converge`, `create`, `destroy`, `test`...) launches a series of steps (a sequence) on your role. You can see the list of steps in the output of the command as in the following example taken from your question when you ran `converge`:

```
└── default
    ├── dependency
    ├── create
    ├── prepare
    └── converge
```

Those sequences are configured by default but can be customized in `molecule.yml` in your scenario directory. You can have a look at a [customization on an open source role I maintain](https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/molecule/default-centos7/molecule.yml#L46) if you are interested in the subject.

By default, a `converge` sequence does not contain a `lint` stage. So you can run your test playbook without having to verify everything.

On the other hand, the `test` sequence includes all of the following steps:

```
└── default
    ├── lint
    ├── dependency
    ├── cleanup
    ├── destroy
    ├── syntax
    ├── create
    ├── prepare
    ├── converge
    ├── idempotence
    ├── side_effect
    ├── verify
    ├── cleanup
    └── destroy
```

As you can see, the first is `lint`, which (by default again) should run [`yamllint`](https://pypi.org/project/yamllint/) on all your yml files, followed by [`ansible-lint`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint) on your role and test playbook and finally [`flake8`](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) on your python files ([`testinfra`](https://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tests, custom modules, custom plugin filters...).

Your full test fails because the best practice checker `ansible-lint` is reporting problems that you should fix. From what I can see they are quite trivial and should go away with a couple lines in your `meta/main.yml`